# Writing a table with values for several years as a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a table I want to write as a Python code, but I'm stuck and can't figure out how to do it.

I have a table with data for two years (1991 and 1992), and different values for each year (men: 35 (1991) and 42 (1992), women: 38 (1991), 39 (1992) and children: 15 (1991), 10 (1992).

What I want is to be able to write one variable (dictionary) in python that makes me able to search for a specific value in a specific year (ex: men(1992) = 42).

My best suggestion so far is to make a dictionary including tuples in something like this:

```
people = {
    'year': (1991, 1992),
    'men': (35, 42),
    'women': (38, 39),
    'children': (15, 10)
    }
```

But this obviously not make it possible to search for both specific values in a specific year.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest something like the following:

```
people = {'1991':{'men':35, 'women':38, 'children':15},
          '1992':{'men':42, 'women':39, 'children':10}}
```

Then you can access specific example data using:

```
print(people['1991']['men'])
```

**EDIT**

If you really need to use tuples and also need the identifiers/keys you will have to use **lists of tuples** like so:

```
people = {'1991':[('men', 35), ('women', 38), ('children', 15)],
              '1992':[('men', 42), ('women', 39), ('children', 10)]}
```

With this variation you can access the same data like:

```
print(people['1991'][0][1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to use tuples inside this, or rewrite it to iclude that? That's what I'm supposed to do, but I am completely lost... Anyways, thank you so much.

Comment: You can use tuples instead of inner dicts, then result would be `people['1991'][0] for men, etc

Comment: Hm... I only get error-message when I try, is there anything else than replacing " { " with " ( " I should do? The message says "statement expected"...

Answer (score 1):

You want a nested dict:

```
people = {
    "men": {
        1991: 35,
        1992: 42
    },
    "women": {
        1991: 38,
        1992: 39
    },
    "children": {
        1991: 15,
        1992: 10
    }
}
```

Now you can do `people['men'][1991]` to get the result 35.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to use tuples inside this, or rewrite it to iclude that? That's what I'm supposed to do, but I am completely lost... Anyways, thank you so much.

Comment: If you want, but I don't know what you want to do with tuples here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put the dictionary in a custom class. This will give you a lot of flexibility regardless of how the data is laid-out in the dictionary itself because you can create methods to add, change, and delete entries in the table that will hide the details of the data structure.

For example, let's say you've decided to organized the data in the dictionary like this:

```
{1991: {'men': 35, 'women': 38, 'children': 15},
 1992: {'men': 42, 'women': 39, 'children': 10}}
```

Then you could wrap that in a class like this:

```
class People(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = {}
    def add(self, year, men, women, children):
        self._data[year] = dict(men=men, women=women, children=children)
    def lookup(self, key, year):
        return self._data[year][key]
    def delete(self, year):
        del self._data[year]

people = People()
people.add(1991, 35, 38, 15)
people.add(1992, 42, 39, 10)

print(people.lookup('women', 1991))  # --> 38
print(people.lookup('men', 1992))  # --> 42
```